# OneNote REST API - How to deal with a "502 Bad Gateway" error?

Tags: rest, onedrive, onenote-api

I asked this question on the OneNote Dev Blog, 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2016/01/13/onenote-api-throttling-and-best-practices.aspx - and Jorge suggested asking it again here.

I am able to create multiple Notebooks with the REST API using the 
POST ...beta/me/notes/notebooks/{master notebook}/copynotebook 
the calls are very fast.

Adding pages with 
POST ...beta/me/notes/pages/{template page}/copyToSection 
works fine and allows me to get the pageID.

This all works as expected until the number of notebooks gets over what seems like a small number of notebooks may be less than 50.
After this any command to get pageIDs such as 
GET .../beta/me/notes/sections/{sectionID}/pages?top=100"

results in multiple "502 Bad Gateway" responses and occassionally gets through after looping for 10-15 minutes waiting for a "200 OK". 
When the notebook count gets to about 100 all page calls fail either in my php script, Fiddler or Microsoft Graph Explorer. Deleting the Notebooks returns functionality.

I know there is a 5000 Notebook limit, but is there a lower limit for pages API functionality (sections and notebook calls continue to work).
Is it possible to select only a subset of Notebooks to be "active" to reduce the overhead on the API call?

My workaround at present (that I'm experiementing with) is to use the OneDrive API to download or move the NoteBooks out of OneDrive to accomplish the same thing - is there another approach?

Comment: Can you share a CorrelationId (HTTP header) of any of the successful requests so we can lookup subsequent data and find a root cause for te 502's?

Comment: Hi Jorge. Here you go. X-CorrelationId: aa2a1068-683b-4fd2-9417-3754e10110f4

Comment: I've just started getting this 502 Bad Gateway error with a simple 3 note GET request in a dev app that had functioned numerous times without issue (first time 15 min before timestamp of this comment).

Adding 'FavorDataRecency: true' to the request header did nothing.

Comment: [17 hours later] All functioning again, as smoothly as before, with no changes in my code. Some issue on the OneNote API backend?

Comment: [21 hrs later] This 502 Bad Gateway error is back : ( - again with no changes in my OneNote API GET code. Inevitable conclusion seems to be some issue on the OneNote API backend.

Comment: [23 hrs later] Functioning again! What gives?

Comment: Experiencing this now myself. The following command: ~/pages?$filter=contains(tolower(parentNotebook/name),'-we')&$expand=parentSection,parentNotebook&$count=true&$top=100 with ***FavorDataRecency:true*** no longer returns a result, even an error and just hangs my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your scenario involves invoking the GET ~/sections/{id}/pages API when you have a large number of sections, we currently recommend adding the below header to your API request.

FavorDataRecency: true

Comment: This should be considered a bug.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, adding **FavorDataRecency:true** fixes the problem, requests that were taking >=120 sec are now completed in ~10 sec. Is there a downside to adding the header? Cheers Steve

Answer (score 0):

1.
In your knowledge, how many pages you had created under the section you are querying from?
2.
Also how many sections per notebook (on average you created)?
3.
Also provide the correlation Id (from the response) for such a request with date, time, time zone of making this request.

There is, however, no limit on the number of pages.

Comment: Hi Sharad,
1.I first query against a section that is empty in a "master" notebook.     
2.The notebooks I am generating contain 7 sections each time (6 generated from copying from the "master" notebook and 1 added with the patient name - this last section comes from a "template page" in a second notebook and is then renamed).
    3.I don't receive a correlation Id, here is a typical response

HTTP\/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: Microsoft-IIS\/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 25 Jan 2016 13:39:25 GMT
Content-Length: 0